# Encontrar y extraer un texto de una Celda en R

Tags: r, substring

Vengo con la siguiente consulta, tengo que extraer de multiples filas y columnas un valor que pude venir escrito de distintas formas, pero tiene un patron, por ejemplo:

VcEde++_HTML1133-2DRtX: Necesito extaer desde el HTML y los siguientes 4 digitos = "HMTL1133"

Tambien puede venir escrito mas de una vez:

VTI_HTML1943-4...1dEtHTML1093 => "HTML1943-4" & "HTML1093"

todos los valores de las celdas vienen con distintas posiciones por lo que no puedo usar Substr dado que la posicion inicial cambia...

Por favor su ayuda

Comment: No entiendo mucho de `r`, pero lo que te sugiero es que busques dentro de la cadena la palabra HTML, y con esto podrías sacar la posición en la que está, y a partir de ahí coger los dígitos que necesites y repetirlo tantas veces como necesites, con ayuda de un bucle por ejemplo. La forma en la que planteas la pregunta parece más que estás buscando que alguien te lo haga más que ayudar con un problema específico. Deberías [edit] la pregunta y poner lo que has intentado, si es que has intentado algo.

Comment: como lo hago? he probado varios codigos pero no se cual entrega la posicion

Comment: Una duda, ¿los números que siguen a HTML son siempre de 4 dígitos?

Comment: El resultado `"HTML1943-4"` debería ser `"HTML1943"` para que cumpla con tu patrón de HTML  y 4 dígitos

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en la [siguiente respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75836183/extract-n-characters-after-pattern-in-string-in-r) a una pregunta similar, bastaría con utilizar la siguiente función:

```
f1 <- function(string, n, chr){
  pat <- sprintf("(?<=%s)%s", chr, strrep(".", n))
  str_extract_all(string, pat)[[1]]
}
```

En el caso del ejemplo que pones, bastaría ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
 # Palabra a analizar
      a <- VTI_HTML1943-4...1dEtHTML1093
   # Los 4 siguientes términos a "HTML" 
     f1(a,4,"HTML")
 [1] "1943" "1093"
```

Como resultado se obtienen los 4 números siguientes al término `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

Se podría usar `sub` así

Consideremos que `string` contiene el texto de tu ejemplo:

```
string <- c("VcEde++_HTML1133-2DRtX", "VTI_HTML1943-4", "1dEtHTML1093")
```

Entonces con `sub` se puede extraer el texto requerido

```
sub(".*(HTML\\d{4}).*", "\\1", string)
[1] "HTML1133" "HTML1943" "HTML1093"
```

Solo que revisa que `HTML1943-4` debería ser `HTML1943` para que cumpla con tu patrón de ser HTML + 4 dígitos.